# How to filter Array values using Data.Lens.Aeson before parsing them?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I have an incoming JSON which looks like:

```
{
  "somekey": [
    { "objectType": "typeA"
    , "key1": "val1"
    , "key2": "val2"
    }
  , { "objectType": "typeB"
    , "key3": "val3"
    , "key4": "val4"
    }
  ]
```

While parsing, I want to deal with ONLY objects tagged with `typeA`. I've got the following code to work, but I'm looking at something more idiomatic that will use the power of lenses properly AND will result in a better error message if the parsing fails:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens (values, key, _String)

instance FromJSON MyType where
  parseJson = Aeson.withObject "Expecting JSON object" $ \o -> do
    allItems <- o .: "someKey"
    let selectedItems :: [Aeson.Value] = filter (\x -> x ^? (key "objectType") . _String == Just "typeA") $ allItems ^.. values 
    someKey <- mapM parseJON selectedItems
    pure MyType{..}
```

Comment: Could you be clearer? If the code works, what behaviour is it that you don't like, and in what way do you think it needs to be more idiomatic?

Comment: I asked this 3 months ago, and have forgotten the exact problem I was trying to solve then. Let me take a guess here, now. If the parsing in `mapM parseJSON selectedItems` fails, will the error message be able to identify which element in the array caused the failure? Also, is there a better lens combinator to achieve what the following expression is doing - `filter (\x -> x ^? (key "objectType") . _String == Just "typeA") $ allItems ^.. values`